# Hierarchy query based on two tables,

Tags: oracle

In my oracle 11g database, I have two tables. The first, `accitem`, holds item information and the second, `acchart` holds chart information. Every row in table `accitem` is unique. There are no repetitions. In the other table, `acchart item_type` refers to a foreign key in the `acchart` table. It looks like so:

```
Accitem
ID         Details
BS         Balance sheet
PL         Profit & loss

acchart

item_code    item_description       item_type
INC          Income                  PL
EXP          Expenses                PL
Ass          Assets                  BS
Eqt          Equity                  BS
```

What I want to achieve is as follows:

```
Balance Sheet
    + Assets
    + Equity

Profit & Loss
   + Income
   + Expenses
```

How would you achieve that?

Comment: I dont understand what exacly are you trying to do. are you trying to blend the two tables into one, where the item types are put with each other?

Comment: Can you give the DDL statements for the tables, some sample data **AND** your expected output for that data?

Comment: it's a simple join.. but then you show it as indented.. so maybe a connect by?

Comment: This is more of a parent child relationship between two tables rather than a hierarchy.  Hierarchical queries are generally multi-generational queries of data from a single self referential table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use `connect by`:

```
select decode(level, 2, ' + ', '')||q.name from
(
select ID, Details name, null parent_id
from accitem
UNION ALL
select null ID, item_description name, item_type parent_id
from acchart
) q
start with parent_id is null
connect by prior id = parent_id
```

Its performance is questionable on larger datasets though.

Comment: spot on, this what i wanted exactally. Many thanks genious